# The minimum number of circles in order to obtain a COVER of a specific square

Tags: geometry, optimization

Suppose a unit square $X$, with side length $l=1$ as below, which is COVERed by a set $Y$ of circles with the same constant radius of $r=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$, where a `cover` set $Y$ of another set $X$ means, $x\in Y,\forall x\in X$.

Questions are :

1) how to obtain the minimum number $n^*$ of circles in $Y$?

2) And I am also interested in the relationship between the ratio $\eta=\dfrac{r}{l}$ of circle radius to the side length of the square, and the number of circles $n^*$.

[image]

I also guess, if the pattern as above is right, then $n^*=\left\lceil {\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2\eta}} \right\rceil^2 $, but don't know how to prove or disprove it. Probably, below is a counter example?
[image]

Comment: You should make it clear in the question that you want to find the minimum number of circles of a FIXED radius that can cover a square of fixed side length. Also what have you tried so far? For instance can you offer a geometric argument to claim that a regularly distributed array of circles is the optimal pattern? (like in your figure).

Comment: I guess for the cover of squares, such a pattern should be the best but have no idea how to prove it; and I think the function $\eta\left(n^*\right)$ should be a step function, but I don't know how to prove it either. e.g, $n^* = \text{Ceiling}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2\eta}\right)^2$

Comment: The lower figure suggests a honeycomb arrangement giving the best average coverage over large areas. I suspect that this problem has many different answers depending on the square/circle ratio. With very small circles, you are better off with the honeycomb scheme across the bulk of it, but you will lose some at the edges; so there may be some range of ratios where the best solution is not a grid but doesn't have a large honeycomb area, either.

Comment: Possible approach is to find a formula for the grid case, given a ratio; and to find a formula for the honeycomb case, given a ratio; between the two you at least have a decent lower bound for any given ratio. The 'grid rotated 45 degrees' scheme might be a bit better for some ratios too.

Comment: This is close to packing problems, which are *hard*.  You could look at [packomania](http://www.packomania.com/) to see that for small numbers things go crazy.  As you go to large numbers, the hexagonal packing can't be beat, then worry about the boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Table 1 of following paper by GK Das et al (2006),

$\hspace0.3in$[Efficient algorithm for placing a given number of base stations to cover a convex region](http://www.cs.ccu.edu.tw/%7Ekorenson/courses/cs5755/07021413061913497.pdf)

the minimum radius for 23 circles to over a unit square is at most $0.14124482238793135951$. Since this is smaller than $\displaystyle\;\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$, at most 23 circles is enough.

<strike>I have no idea how the configuration for 23 circles look like. However,</strike> following is a
[page](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovsqu/)
which has the configuration of best known covering of a square by up to $12$ equal circles.
As your can see, the configuration doesn't seem to follow any obvious pattern. It is highly
unlikely that $n^{*}$ has any simple formula.

**Update**

The configurations in Table 1 are computed in a research notes (Ref 15 in GK Das' paper)

$\hspace0.3in$[Covering a square with up to 30 equal circles](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.3894) by K.J. Nurmela, P.R.J. Ostergard

An online copy (in postscript) is available [here](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/old/reports/A62.ps.gz). It has pictures for configuration up to 30 circles.

Based on above paper, following is one way to cover the unit square with 23 circles
of radius $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$.
For simplicity of presentation, we will center the unit square at the origin and
only show the $8$ circles on the first quadrant.

[image: Cover 1/4 square by 8 circles]

In this configuration, the centers of the circles are positioned at:

$$\begin{array}{|c:l|}
\hline
\text{eg.} & (x,y)\\
\hline
A, B, C & (0,0), (\pm 0.25,0), (\pm 0.5,0)\\
D, E & (\pm 0.125,\pm 0.20756513901392), (\pm 0.375,\pm0.20756513901392)\\
F & (0, \pm 0.41513027802785)\\
G & (\pm 0.22172066050239,\pm 0.40940831933773)\\
H & (\pm 0.41515845958082,\pm 0.38685446089527)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The centers of the middle 3 layers (i.e those in the same layers as $A,B,C,D,E$) are forming a triangular lattice elongated in the vertical direction.

Comment: can you also indicate the arrangement of the circles?

Comment: Thank you! It seems for general cases, there is no global solution. This answer is very helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Well just few thoughts for the problem. The formula for dimension **$l=ne^d$** the area that covers a circle is $ E=πρ^2$ and for Square is $E=a^2$ so if we try solve this in order to find the radius, then we take the following result this is if you want a constant radius otherwise if you want multiple circles you have to find the sum $ \sum_{i=1}^n ρ_i =\pm a /\sqrt{\pi} $
for interpretation you can use formulas of Gregory and Leibniz or Abraham Sharp

a = value of square side 
ρ = radius 
π = 3,14...
Ε = Area
l = length 
n = number of shapes 
d = dimension
e = the characteristic value of the shape (radius for circle , side for square)